# Rails: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

apparently there is a thread that addresses this issue . But I have already tried to run those commands given in the solution. I am still getting the same error for some reason.

I run 
`gem install mysql2 -v  0.3.18`

followed by 
`bundle install`

on my terminal. And than I start the server by typing 
rails server

Upon opening the localhost:3000. I receive the same error.

> Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your rails version?

Comment: Rails  4.2.4 is my version

Comment: Did you try adding `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'` to your `Gemfile` and then running `bundle install`?

Comment: I just did. It removed the last error but gave me this:

Comment: rescue Mysql2::Error => error
      if error.message.include?("Unknown database")
        raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError.new(error.message, error)
      else
        raise
      end

Comment: When I tried to open the localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I just did. I replaced gem 'mysql2' with gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'

Comment: Now I am receiving this Error:      rescue Mysql2::Error => error
      if error.message.include?("Unknown database")
        raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError.new(error.message, error)
      else
        raise
      end

Comment: did you run `rake db:create`?

Comment: That message just means you don't have the database yet. You need to create the database first.

Comment: Do: `bundle exec rake db:create` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and then try again.

Comment: Thanks man. I just commented out the database part in database.yml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90846/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-haris-ghauri).