# Ruby on Rails error: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Ok I have read countless articles on this same problem and I cannot get past this. I am new to Rails and I don't know much about what I'm doing but I get this error every time I run a rails server:

Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

```
require path_to_adapter
      rescue Gem::LoadError => e
        raise Gem::LoadError, "Specified '#{spec[:adapter]}' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem '#{e.name}'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)."
      rescue LoadError => e
        raise LoadError, "Could not load '#{path_to_adapter}'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.", e.backtrace
      end
```

What do I do? I've done everything on these two threads but nothing changes.

[Gem::LoadError for mysql2 gem, but it's already in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932282/gemloaderror-specified-mysql2-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-is-not-loade)

[Rails: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter but the gem is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835912/ruby-on-rails-error-specified-mysql2-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-is-not)

Comment: Are you using a gem manager like RVM or rbenv or chruby?

Comment: @claptimes I dont know im following along with the first derek banas video and i think its just ruby, rails, and mysql

Comment: Can you try using `bundle exec <command>` for example `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: I did bundle exec rails s and it started a rails server. In that server I still have the same problem lol

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error with Rails 4. I have down graded mysql2 gem 0.4.x to 0.3.20 in my Gemfile. Then ran `bundle upgrade mysql2`

Comment: yes i downgraded it to 0.3.18 like a lot of people said to. I tried changing mysql2 gem to 0.3.20 and when I run bundle upgrade mysql2: Could not find command "upgrade".

Comment: here is a pastebin of what my output to that command looks like: http://pastebin.com/3gFuGzEP

Comment: You need to just run `bundle`

Comment: "You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control." - This shows up if you have deployed your code and changed the Gemfile on the deployment machine. If you are on your development machine follow the instructions bundle is suggesting.

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee thank you so much i didnt know this was a development machine and now i feel silly, the answer was in front of me for so long! claptimes thank you too both you guys responded and helped me out a lot. have a great day!